# Windows 7 Updating Java, Adobe Reader and Creative Software every boot

Tags: windows-7

Every time I boot my system I get software update notifications for Java, Adobe Reader and my Creative Soundblaster card.

I then install the updates, but every time I reboot, it says that there are updates for them again. This has been happening for a couple months. It's annoying.

Anyone know any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try running the updaters with explicit Administrator permission (right-click the app and select 'Run As Administrator')?

Another option is to uninstall and reinstall the applications themselves.

Comment: I will try this suggestion when I get home. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, disable the updaters or download the latest version of this software directly from the website and install it. I'd suggest the second option for security.

Java updater can be disabled in **Control Panel -> Java**.

Adobe Updater can be disabled by opening Reader and going to **Edit -> Preferences -> Updater**.

Creative should have something similar although I do not have the software.

Comment: Ideally, I would like the updaters to be enabled, and then after I update them, they will only notify me of new updates instead of every time I boot the system. Currently I have to update Java and adobe etc everyday, or just cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as the options of the updaters, you can change the event that decides when to check for updates to something on a weekly basis rather than on boot.